# InvalidParameterError: The 'scoring' parameter of GridSearchCV must be a str among

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

When I try to fit the training dataset to the GridsearchCV, it states that the scoring must be a str among:

```
{'jaccard_samples', 'precision_macro', 'balanced_accuracy', ...<long list of allowed classes, see edit history>...}, 
a callable, an instance of 'list', an instance of 'tuple', an instance of 'dict' or None. 
Got {'precision', 'recall', 'accuracy', 'f1'} instead."
```

Even though my scoring is a list of: `"{'precision','f1','recall','accuracy'}"`.

I run the code with the Jupyter kernel extension in VS code. I tried changing it to only go for the scoring of 'Recall' and it worked, however that I would like to have multiple scoring variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The allowed types for `scoring` in [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) are

> str, callable, list, tuple or dict,

You are passing a set which is not a valid type.

Use `scoring=['precision','f1','recall','accuracy']` with square brackets not curly ones.

---

To more comprehensive for multiple scoring types you can pass (see linked doc) :

> - a list or tuple of unique strings;
> - a callable returning a dictionary where the keys are the metric names and the values are the metric scores;
> - a dictionary with metric names as keys and callables a values.

---

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I'm quite new to coding so I really appreciate the help! :)